# Magic wand tool

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I am using adobe illustrator 2021. But if I select magic wand tool. Nothing happens. The selection is not visible.

I just don't understand.

[image]

And the original

[image]

Thank you

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. Why are you trying to edit a raster image in Illustrator?  Illustrator is a vector image editor. Use Photohsop for editing raster images, not Illustrator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As discussed [here](https://community.adobe.com/t5/illustrator/cannot-use-magic-wand-tool-and-magic-lasso-tool/m-p/9577748), Illustrator Magic Wand is different from Photoshop or any other raster program. You can use Illustrator Magic Wand on vectors, **not** raster layers or placed images. Your image is a raster object. I have not tried Illustrator 2021, but I'm sure the feature is still same.

To verify, you can create a random vector object and then try Magic Wand on it and it will work. You'll know it isn't some fault in Illustrator, it is the intended behavior.

If you need basic crop of this image in particular shape like circle/oval/square, you can use clipping mask.

You can create a complex path too using pen tool for detailed clipping mask, but you'll need more time. For example, in case you want to 'crop' human figure. But raster program is still recommended.

Comment: Oke, thank you. But you can use PNG for it right?

Comment: @mightycodeNewton sorry I didn't get it?

Comment: I mean for the magic wand tool, you can use PNG for it?

Comment: @mightycodeNewton no. No image would work irrespective of extensions.

Comment: oH MY god. I just used. EPS format. and it works oke, thank you

Comment: EPS file is vector file.

Comment: You can also use it on jpg when you first convert them into a vector by clicking the top left "image trace" and then embed buttons